# ionic angular project my build failed ... error

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, build

**build error**

[image: Build error]

> hey guys I am stucked with the build error for many days please help
> me regarding this error I have tried upgrading gradle version and
> android gradle plugin version since it wont work for me

Comment: Hi, do you using capacitor ? If yes what version do you use for android maybe you should update the version capacitor@android

Comment: Looking at the build log he's using Cordova.

Comment: capacitor version is 3.1.2 @EmreAkbaki

Comment: If you are using capacitor you don't need to use cordova. You can use cordova plugins with capacitor. Check this out:> https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor